# Pagination and queryset

Tags: django, pagination

I have a queryset :

```
items = Items.objects.all()
category_query = request.POST.get('category)
items = items.filter(category = category_query)
```

I have a paginator :

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
paginator = Paginator(items, 18)
page_query = request.GET.get('page')
items = paginator.get_page(page_query)
```

when I click on Next in the pagination it remove the active filter on my items. How can I avoid that ?

Comment: Pass your parameter to the pagination button with get. `{% url 'items_list' %}?category=fiction`

Comment: thanks but category is dynamic, not fixed

Answer (score 0):

### Use Django List View.

Django list View provide default pagination feature respective query-set.
Please follow the attach URL.

[Django List View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

Comment: Thanks but my quersyset is dynamic. User select a category in form and do a POST.

Comment: I don't find any mention of ability to do a request.POST.get in listview ?